# XAMPP: mysql shuts down every day or two, Needs to restart xampp every time

Tags: mysql, xampp

Everything was working fine, but now I get error in browser while visiting my websites "error establishing database connection". Error gets solved after restarting xampp, and what I observe every time that mysql module of xampp stops running.

Few months ago this error was coming every 15 days, and I always solved this issue by restarting xampp, but now it occurs very frequently(everyday or in 2 days).

I also tried one solution "deleting the file ibdata1" that helped me for 3-4 days, and problem started again.

**here is my error log:**
[Mon Dec 05 14:36:21.001921 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7479] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Dec 05 14:36:21.001985 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7479] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Dec 05 14:36:21.002084 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 7479] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Mon Dec 05 14:36:21.050579 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7480] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Dec 05 14:36:22.001567 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7480] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Dec 05 14:36:22.001605 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7480] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Dec 05 14:36:22.001713 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 7480] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Dec 05 14:36:22.019204 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7480] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 05 14:36:22.019244 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7480] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
[Tue Dec 06 05:25:35.571290 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7480] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

It is big problem to me as well as visitors of my websites.

Please guys, If any one of you know how to solve this issue, do reply.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on my website.

In my case it was the cron upgrade proces which gave an MySQL error. After fixing this no restarts where needed anymore.